# Double CHOOSE function in Excel?

Tags: excel, function, charts

Here's what I want to do.
I have 3 sets of rows... every set has 4 rows...I want to use this data for a chart. So I used a CHOOSE function to get the values from one of the sets in place where I get my data for the chart.
Now... I want to add another list to choose the row and see just one line (in the chart) (instead of 4). Is there any way to do this?

So... I have 3 sets with 4 rows each. I want to have a list where I can select the set and another list where I can select the row of the set.
Is this possible with CHOOSE function or any other function in Excel? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will `INDEX` work for you? Try this version

`=INDEX((SetOne,SetTwo,SetThree),n,0,m)`

where m is the set number (1, 2 or 3) and n is the row number (1, 2, 3 or 4), so obviously this formula

`=INDEX((SetOne,SetTwo,SetThree),4,0,3)`

will give you the 4th row in SetThree

although I'm not sure if you can use a "union" in a chart definition so another way with `CHOOSE` in `INDEX`......

`=INDEX(CHOOSE(3,SetOne,SetTwo,SetThree),4,0)`

that also gets you 4th row from SetThree......

Answer (score 0):

I would probably make another line from which the chart picks his data.
So... I do 4 lines that are picked based on the first dropdown list and another line from where the charts picks it's data that changes when the second dropdown list is used...